# PHP regular expression not working properly

Tags: php, regex

So I am trying to validate phone numbers with the form xxx-xxx-xxxx where x is a digit.
The problem I am having is I can enter more than 4 digits for the last group of numbers. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```
    $telNumPattern = '/[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}/'; //regular expression to match xxx-xxx-xxxx
    if(empty($_POST['telNum'])) {
        $errors['telNum'] = "*Your telephone number can't be empty";
    }
    else if(!preg_match($telNumPattern, $_POST['telNum'])) {
        $errors['telNum'] = "*Your email must be in the form xxx-xxx-xxxx";
    }
```

Comment: Use the start/end-of-string markers: `/^....$/` so that the pattern won't allow extra stuff at the start/end of the string.

Comment: @MarcB I feel like there should be a canonical answer for this kind of thing we can Mjolnir with...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: you can always start a  question with a community wiki answer to become the hammer-time target.

Comment: @MarcB [Done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894140/regular-expression-matches-more-than-it-should/26894141#26894141)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$telNumPattern = '/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/';
```

Use anchors to make an exact match.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this its working :**

```
$telNumPattern = '/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/'; //regular expression to match xxx-xxx-xxxx
    if(empty($_POST['telNum'])) {
        $errors['telNum'] = "*Your telephone number can't be empty";
    }
    else if(!preg_match($telNumPattern, $_POST['telNum'])) {
        $errors['telNum'] = "*Your email must be in the form xxx-xxx-xxxx";
    }
```